# How can I test one, more or none images in a page with Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, bdd, webrat

I want to test if I have 0, 1, 2 or 3 times a pictures ('foo.png') in a certain page with Cucumber.

How should I write the custom step?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a custom cucumber step that uses a custom rspec expectation matcher.

The sudo code would look something like this.

features/page.feature

```
Given I am on the images page
Then I should see 3 images
```

features/step_definitions/page_steps.rb

This file would use nokogiri to collect all the images with a given name and then use rspec to validate your expectation.

```
Then /^I should see (.+) images$/ do |num_of_images|
   html = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
   tags = html.xpath('//img[@src="/public/images/foo.png"]')
   tags.length.should eql(num_of_images)
end
```

Here is a working Rspec example that shows how to use Nokogiri with Rspec

```
require 'nokogiri'

describe "ImageCount" do 

  it "should have 4 image" do
    html = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><div id=""><img src="/public/images/foo.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/foo.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/foo.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/foo.png"></div>    </html></body>')
    tags = html.xpath('//img[@src="/public/images/foo.png"]')
    tags.length.should eql(4)
  end

  it "should have 3 image" do
    html = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><div id=""><img src="/public/images/bar.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/foo.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/foo.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/foo.png"></div>    </html></body>')
    tags = html.xpath('//img[@src="/public/images/foo.png"]')
    tags.length.should eql(3)
  end

  it "should have 1 image" do
    html = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><div id=""><img src="/public/images/bar.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/aaa.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/bbb.png"></div>    <div id=""><img src="/public/images/foo.png"></div>    </html></body>')
    tags = html.xpath('//img[@src="/public/images/foo.png"]')
    tags.length.should eql(1)
  end

end
```

Comment: Also this line "tags.length.should eql(1)" could be cleaned up.  It should be something like "tags.should have(1)"

Comment: Note that this will only work for Cucumber + Webrat. If you are using Capybara, you will need to change `response.body` to `page.body`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way using capybara:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see (\d+) images?$/ do |count|
  all("img").length.should == count.to_i
end
```